# how to use a .net dll with static utility functions in unity 5?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, unity-game-engine

I have a **.NET 3.5** .dll build with VS2015 that contains some static utility functions and has no further dependencies. What I want to achieve is to use those utility functions in a **C# Script** in my Unity 5.5 (personal edition) project.

I dragged the .dll into the assets browser and created a new C# Script. Unfortunately there was no automatic reference to the .dll, and I wasn't able to find any possibility to add one.

This is what unity shows when doubleclicking on the dll:
[image]

How can I use my (not in any way to Unity related) dll in my Unity C# Script?

Comment: Unity runs on .NET 2.0, so you might not be able to at all. There are ways to write wrappers around arbitrary dlls, but you won't get any code-hinting when writing those wrappers. You have to know what they contain already.  Then the wrapper is used for code-hinting.

Answer (score 0):

Unity runs on Mono not on .NET - that's different things.

Use one of [Unity target frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmNFW.png) (set in VS project properties) when compiling dll outside Unity environment or use PInvoke.

Put dll file into ["Plugins"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html) folder.